# How to install .CSI file for Code Signing and load app to BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry, code-signing

I've developed a PhoneGap application that I intend to deploy to my BlackBerry Bold 9700.  My development tools includes NotePad++, Apache Ant, Sun JDK and BlackBerry WebWorks SDK as dictated on this page here http://www.phonegap.com/start#blackberry.

I applied for Signing Keys from the Blackberry website and received a .CSI file via email.  The email offers instructions for various ways of processing the .CSI file, but none of the ways explain how to do it with the current tools I have installed.

Is there an easy way to proceed with my .CSI file without installing Eclipse, Visual Studio or any other IDE?  If so, can someone dictate step by step what to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope you got the solution for that. I was having the same issues. I hope my solution will work for anyone.

After getting the *.csi files from blackberry, you need to install them on your computer. 
For those of you who are using Ant to build applications which described here http://www.phonegap.com/start#blackberry. 
this will work you.

For installing the *.csi files in your computer you need SignatureTool.jar . This is located in your c:\BBWP\bin directory.

Next copy all the *.csi files to the above directory and run this command from the terminal in sequence.

c:\BBWP\bin>SignatureTool.jar client-RBB-2053305203.csi

c:\BBWP\bin>SignatureTool.jar client-RCR-2053305203.csi

c:\BBWP\bin>SignatureTool.jar client-RRT-2053305203.csi

If you don't have a private key installed you need to create one. And use the pin number which you used during the registration process. The installation is easy you will not have any problems with it.

Hope it helps anyone

Thank you

Comment: thanks, the actual command I typed was `java -jar SignatureTool.jar <.csi file path>`

Comment: i have done above steps using command prompt. Then what can i do

Comment: please help me. I need to sign my .cod file which is created in blackberry phonegap

Comment: i got solution please use c:\BBWP\bin>java -jar SignatureTool.jar client-RRT-2053305203.csi then refer https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/signing_setup_smartphone_apps_1920010_11.html

Answer (score 1):

Try [BlackBerry Ant tools](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/docs). It uses ant so you need it, but this is fairly lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

Look at ["Signing your smartphone application"](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/ww_publishing/signing_your_ww_smartphone_app_1877288_11.html) to get you started